# Mongoose query where value is not null

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Looking to do the following query:

```
Entrant
    .find
      enterDate : oneMonthAgo
      confirmed : true
    .where('pincode.length > 0')
    .exec (err,entrants)->
```

Am I doing the where clause properly? I want to select documents where `pincode` is not null.

Answer (score 275, accepted):

You should be able to do this like (as you're using the query api):

```
Entrant.where("pincode").ne(null)
```

... which will result in a mongo query resembling:

```
entrants.find({ pincode: { $ne: null } })
```

A few links that might help:

- [The mongoose query api](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-ne)
- [The docs for mongo query operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/)

Comment: "not equal", adding links to the answer

Comment: the mongodb docs about it are here (now):
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/
The up-to-date doc about it, is here: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-ne

Comment: How to achieve with array, e.g. `...("myArraySubDoc[0].someValue").ne(true)` ?

Comment: @SirBenBenji something like `where("myArraySubDoc.0.someValue").ne(true)`

Comment: i want to search in an array if it is not present then i want to perform a specific task now can you please tell me how can i do this ??

Answer (score 24):

[$ne](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/)

> selects the documents where the value of the field is not equal to
>   the specified value. This includes documents that do not contain the
>   field.

```
User.find({ "username": { "$ne": 'admin' } })
```

[$nin](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/)

> $nin selects the documents where: 
>   the field value is not in the specified array or the field does not exist.

```
User.find({ "groups": { "$nin": ['admin', 'user'] } })
```

Answer (score 10):

I ended up here and my issue was that I was querying for

```
{$not: {email: /@domain.com/}}
```

instead of

```
{email: {$not: /@domain.com/}}
```

Comment: Just a note this is exactly what I was looking for myself, thanks!

Comment: I was struggling to find $not in the api doc! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ok guys I found a possible solution to this problem. I realized that joins do not exists in Mongo, that's why first you need to query the user's ids with the role you like, and after that do another query to the profiles document, something like this:

```
    const exclude: string = '-_id -created_at -gallery -wallet -MaxRequestersPerBooking -active -__v';

  // Get the _ids of users with the role equal to role.
    await User.find({role: role}, {_id: 1, role: 1, name: 1},  function(err, docs) {

        // Map the docs into an array of just the _ids
        var ids = docs.map(function(doc) { return doc._id; });

        // Get the profiles whose users are in that set.
        Profile.find({user: {$in: ids}}, function(err, profiles) {
            // docs contains your answer
            res.json({
                code: 200,
                profiles: profiles,
                page: page
            })
        })
        .select(exclude)
        .populate({
            path: 'user',
            select: '-password -verified -_id -__v'
            // group: { role: "$role"} 
          })
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

total count the documents where the value of the field is not equal to the specified value.

```
async function getRegisterUser() {
    return Login.count({"role": { $ne: 'Super Admin' }}, (err, totResUser) => {
        if (err) {
            return err;
        }
        return totResUser;
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello guys I am stucked with this. I've a Document Profile who has a reference to User,and I've tried to list the profiles where user ref is not null (because I already filtered by rol during the population), but
after googleing a few hours I cannot figure out how to get this. I
have this query:

> ```
> const profiles = await Profile.find({ user: {$exists: true,  $ne: null }})
>                             .select("-gallery")
>                             .sort( {_id: -1} )
>                             .skip( skip )
>                             .limit(10)
>                             .select(exclude)
>                             .populate({
>                                 path: 'user',
>                                 match: { role: {$eq: customer}},
>                                 select: '-password -verified -_id -__v'
>                               })
>
>                             .exec();
>
> And I get this result, how can I remove from the results the user:null colletions? . I meant, I dont want to get the profile when user is null (the role does not match).
> {
>     "code": 200,
>     "profiles": [
>         {
>             "description": null,
>             "province": "West Midlands",
>             "country": "UK",
>             "postal_code": "83000",
>             "user": null
>         },
>         {
>             "description": null,
>
>             "province": "Madrid",
>             "country": "Spain",
>             "postal_code": "43000",
>             "user": {
>                 "role": "customer",
>                 "name": "pedrita",
>                 "email": "myemail@gmail.com",
>                 "created_at": "2020-06-05T11:05:36.450Z"
>             }
>         }
>     ],
>     "page": 1
> }
> ```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should not ask your questions in the form of answers

Comment:  This is one way to go about it, next will be posting answers instead of questions